# not able get flashdata in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my controller code

```
function index() {
    echo $this->session->flashdata('message');
    $this->load->view('categoryView');
}

function delete() {
    $products = $this->item_model->get_category_id($category_id);
    if (count($products)) {
        $message = 'Category Name is used by the product. Please change them to another category!';
    }
    else {
        $category_id = $this->product_category_model->delete($category_id);
        $message = ($category_id) ? 'Category Deleted Successfully' : 'Failed to Delete Category';
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
    redirect('category', 'refresh');
}
```

After calling the delete function the flashdata has to be set and retrieve that value in index() function of the same controller but I can't.

Am also tried the $this->session->keep_flashdata('message'); before redirect to index function. But still am not get any value in index function.

Also changed $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE; to $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE; Still am not get the result.

I am wasted more time(nearly half day). Please anybody help to retrieve the flas data in codeigniter.

Comment: sorry but have you autoloaded Session?

Comment: So the echo in the index file does nothing?

Comment: I have auto loaded session and already am used the session class that working fine but flash data only not working

Comment: yes. echo in index function not show anything

Answer (score 0):

There are several probabilities:

1- Check your browser cookie. See if it allows cookies or if any other extension is intervening.

2- `Refresh` might not send the browser a new request (which thus mean a new URL). Try it for another controller see if it make any change

3- hard code the `set_flashdata()` with hard-coded value than a variable. `set_flashdata("message", "Thank you");`

Comment: Hi M T, Thanks for your valuable answer. I am tried like you said as controller to controller. That working fine. But I am tried to get that flasdata in the same controller means can't able to get? Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

In codeingitor you cannot echo anything in controller.

You have to set  in `$this->session->flashdata('message');` in view file not in index() function of controller

Try again by putting `$this->session->flashdata('message');` in "categoryView" file where you want to display flash message.

Comment: you can echo things. Who said that? Just echo it to see it gets echoed. But it is not a good practice to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
function set_flashdata_notification($notify_type, $msg, $error_code = null)
{
    $ci =& get_instance();

    $flashdata_data = set_notification_array($notify_type, $msg, $error_code);
    $ci->session->set_flashdata($flashdata_data);
}

function delete() {
$products = $this->item_model->get_category_id($category_id);
if (count($products)) {
    set_flashdata_notification('Category Name is used by the product.','Please change them to another category!');
    redirect('path_to_view/view','refresh');
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between set_flashdata_notification() and set_flashdata()

Comment: If am use the set_flashdata_notification() then undefined function error is gets display.

Comment: At last of the set_flahdata_notification(), you are set the flashdata by set_flashdata(). For that function the array is passed as data right. Why we need to do like this, instead we can directly use the set_flashdata(). Don't feel to share your ideas